# Can't force RTL on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

When using `FolowDirection` with `RightToLeft` for elements in XAML, it works fine.

However, I want to set it by default and force it throughout the app.

Followed [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left#android-2) but nothing is happening, setting `Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection` does not seem to do anything.

I have also set: `<application android:label="App.Android" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>`

Here is my Android project code:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection = Android.Views.LayoutDirection.Rtl;

    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to set it by default and force it throughout the app.

Firstly , we should know that the direction of the app is based on the device language and region .So you need to make sure that the setting of language and region is RTL (like Arabic) .

You could check it in code behind

```
var flowDirection = Device.FlowDirection; // this is a readonly property
```

If you do want to set your app as RTL while don't change the system setting . You could create a base **ContentPage** and setting the FlowDirection of it . The value will be inherited by all of its children (unless you override it) .

```
public partial class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
  public BaseContentPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
  }
}
```

If you want to let a specific element (like a label) still LTR , you just need to  set the FlowDirection property on the label to **LeftToRight**.

Comment: What about the official documentation? I have also tried in the past to set it globally with Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection but to no success. And yes, I have changed my phone language to RTL one.

Comment: I have set the language to Arabic, but to no avail. I accessed `Device.FlowDirection` and to my surprise it is `RightToLeft`. I will upload a sample repo. I tried both XF 4.3 and latest 4.6 and the result is same.

Comment: From your demo I couldn't where did you set `FlowDirection` . It is necessary .

Comment: You could test my solution(define BaseContentPage) .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT hmm, I think I understand what is going on. From docs, `The default FlowDirection property value for an element without a parent is LeftToRight, while the default FlowDirection for an element with a parent is MatchParent.` So basically the default is gonna be LeftToRight, and we have to set it explicitly otherwise. No need to set the language to RTL or anything. If so, then what is the point of setting the layout direction in MainActivity as the docs says. So weird. Gonna open a ticket in that docs page. Thanks for your help.